# WCF Restful Client throwing "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed."

Tags: wcf-client, wcf-rest

I am a newbie at WCF. I created a WCF restful service in VS2010 (WCF service appl). It was targeted for Framework 4.0. I hosted this service on local IIS with appl pool set for framework 4.0. When I call the appl methods from browser or fiddler, they work fine. Now, I created a client console based. When I call any method from client I get the following Communication Exception:

** remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.**

**Service Interface file:**

```
namespace MyService
```

{

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{


    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetDateTime")]
    [OperationContract]
    string GetDateTime();

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetName")]
    [OperationContract]
    string GetName();

}
```

}

**Class that implements the above interface:**

```
namespace MyService
```

{

```
 public class TestService : ITestService
    {
        public string GetDateTime()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return "MY name is KingKong";
    }
}
```

}

**Web.config file:**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="MyService.TestService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="MyService.ITestService">

    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

**TestService.svc**

<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MyService.TestService" CodeBehind="TestService.svc.cs" %>

**Client app.config:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <webHttp />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/BestService/TestService.svc"
            binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="MyService.ITestService"
            name="MyClientConfig" kind="" endpointConfiguration="" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Client program calling proxy class**

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestServiceClient proxy = null;
        try
        {
            proxy = new TestServiceClient();

            Console.WriteLine("Test 1: List all products");
            string sdatetime = proxy.GetName();

            Console.WriteLine("Datetime: {0}", sdatetime);

            Console.WriteLine();

            // Disconnect from the service
            proxy.Close();


        }
        catch (CommunicationException cex)
        {

            if (cex.InnerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", cex.InnerException.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("General exception: {0}", cex.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.InnerException.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("General exception: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to finish");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

**I added a service reference to the application and the Reference.cs file has following partial code:**

namespace MyClient.MyService {

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="MyService.ITestService")]
public interface ITestService {

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ITestService/GetDateTime", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ITestService/GetDateTimeResponse")]
    string GetDateTime();

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ITestService/GetName", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ITestService/GetNameResponse")]
    string GetName();
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface ITestServiceChannel : MyClient.MyService.ITestService, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class TestServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<MyClient.MyService.ITestService>, MyClient.MyService.ITestService {

    public TestServiceClient() {
    }

    public TestServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName) {
    }

    public TestServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public TestServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public TestServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public string GetDateTime() {
        return base.Channel.GetDateTime();
    }

    public string GetName() {
        return base.Channel.GetName();
    }
}
```

}

Please help me as I have spent nearly 2 days trying to figure out the problem in the client

Thanks

Comment: This is just **too much stuff!** Can you narrow it down to a simple service, one single method, and debug it?? ....

Comment: FYI: http://localhost/BestService/TestService.svc/ <== BestService is the name of the virtaul directory on IIS pointing to the WCF service application folder where the TestService.svc file is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS2010 doesnt have the ability to generate a proxy for a RESTFUL service as it does for a SOAP based service. So the solution is write your own proxy class which inherits from the ClientBase class and use the Channel to call the web methods of the service.